# How to get the particular row id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a grid with 4 columns:

1. Name
2. Quantity
3. Cost
4. Total Cost

In these 4 `Name` and `Cost` will come from database and `Quantity` is a text field. When we enter the value into text field it should go to java and perform the `Quantity * Cost` and populate the `totalcost` .This is my requirement. For this I am using the following code:

In my jsp i have a container like this:

```
<div id="search-results-list" class="green-results-list" style="height: 150px; width: 697px;">
</div>
Handler.setupGrid();
```

And in my js file in setupGrid i have the following lines of code.

```
setupGrid : function() {

        $('.green-results-list').html('');
        $.post('note.json', 'action=get-grid-data', function(obj) {
            var data = obj.result.data;
            if(data !== undefined){
                if(data.length>0) {
                    var rowstr = '';
                    for(var x=0;x<data.length;x=x+1) {
                        rowstr=rowstr+'<div class="ui-content report-content">';
                        rowstr=rowstr+'<div class="report-body" style="width: 697px;height: 50px;">';
                        rowstr=rowstr+'<div class="report-body-column2 centered" style="height: 41px; width: 150px">'+data[x].name+'</div>';
                        rowstr=rowstr+'<div class="report-body-column2 centered" style="height: 41px; width: 150px">'+'<input type = "text"  class="quantity" size=10px>'+'</div>';
                        rowstr=rowstr+'<div class="report-body-column2 centered" style="height: 41px; width: 150px">'+data[x].cost+'</div>';
                        rowstr=rowstr+'<div class="report-body-column2 centered" style="height: 41px; width: 150px">'+data[x].totalCost+'</div>';
                        rowstr=rowstr+'</div></div>';
                        }
                    $('.green-results-list').append(rowstr);

                } else {
                $('.green-results-list').html('<div class="success-msg">No Data Exist.</div>');
            }
        }else {
            $('.green-results-list').html('<div class="success-msg">No Data Exist.</div>');
        }
    });

    }
```

When I enter the value into text field I am getting the text field value using the below lines of code:

```
$('.quantity').live("blur",function(){
    var data = $(this).val();
    alert(data);
 });
```

Using this I am getting the text field value.
But my problem is when I enter the value into text field `totalCost` of that particular row only needs to get effected.

How can I do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You and Sorry for my poor English. I hope you are able to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find 'row' using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function for example

```
var $row = $(this).closest("div");
```

**upd:**

and get div's text using [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or HTML using [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) functions

```
var text = $row.text();
var html = $tow.html();
```

I would recommend you learn the basics first. For example from [Try jQuery](http://try.jquery.com/) screencasts.

Comment: Hi Thank You very much for giving the response.If i do like above i am getting the object but how can i set the data(textfield data) to this id.Actually i am very new to this jquery.

Comment: I've added a few examples.